# PostgreSQL create extension mongo_fdw

Tags: linux, mongodb, postgresql

I want to connect a PostgreSQL database with a MongoDB by using Mongo_fdw. After following [this](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw) instruction to install mongo_fdw with the `autogen.sh` script on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I wanted to check the connection and ran `CREATE EXTENSION mongo_fdw;` in my database, but the following error occured:

```
ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/mongo_fdw": No such file or directory
```

Searchig for a solution I found [this](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw/issues/134) page on GitHub, where the same error is discussed. Following the recommendations there, I checked `pg_config --version`, `pg_config --libdir` and `pg_config --sharedir` with the following results:

```
$ pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 12.9
$ pg_config --libdir
/home/qgis/anaconda3/lib
$ pg_config --sharedir
/home/qgis/anaconda3/share
```

When I check `/home/qgis/anaconda3/share/extension` I get the following files:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 qgis qgis 4096 Feb  1 10:58 ./
drwxrwxr-x 32 qgis qgis 4096 Jan 18 10:28 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  157 Feb  1 10:58 mongo_fdw--1.0--1.1.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  593 Feb  1 10:58 mongo_fdw--1.0.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  709 Feb  1 10:58 mongo_fdw--1.1.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  274 Feb  1 10:58 mongo_fdw.control
-rw-rw-r--  2 qgis qgis  310 Jun 24  2022 plpgsql--1.0.sql
-rw-rw-r--  2 qgis qgis  179 Jun 24  2022 plpgsql.control
-rw-rw-r--  2 qgis qgis  370 Jun 24  2022 plpgsql--unpackaged--1.0.sql
```

I also ran `ldconfig` as it is recommended on the [GitHub](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw) page but with no results.

Does someone has an idea how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I giess you have several PostgreSQL installations and installed the software in the wrong one. I would be surprised if your PostgreSQL server uses software installed in `/home/qgis/anaconda3`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just run `which psql` and got the result `/usr/bin/psql`, is this the correct direction?

Comment: No, that is the client. Try something like `locate postgres`.

Comment: Now I found postgresql several directions. The most likely are: `/etc/postgresql/14`,  `usr/lib/postgresql/14`, `usr/share/doc/postgresql-14` and `usr/share/postgresql/14` which of them is the correct one?

Comment: You have shown us the listing of sharedir, but not of libdir.  Note that error message mentions libdir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the correct `pg_config` when building the software, probably

```bash
make PG_CONFIG=/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_config
```

That file should exist if you installed the package with the C headers, which is typically called "devel" or "dev" or similar.

Comment: I run the command you recommended (pg_config is indeed in this folder) but the error still exists.

Comment: You'll have to figure out which PostgreSQL software you are using.

Comment: Thank you! I was in the correct `pg_config` but I had to run first `sudo make clean`, then `sudo PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/:$PATH make CC=gcc` and
`sudo PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/:$PATH make install` after that it worked!